# Custom Search using DjangoFilterBackend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to search againt multiple columns. I have used DjangoFilterBackend for this purpose. This package uses

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/contacts/?first_name=Clair&last_name=Test
```

I want to customize this pattern as,

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/contacts/?query[first_name]=Clair&query[last_name]=Test
```

How can I customize DjangoFilterBackend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this specific pattern customization? REST generally uses this pattern for filtering by multiple values for the same field:

Answer (score 0):

**This is a hack**; but if you need to you can create a custom `BaseFilterSet` that supports this URL scheme. You will need to do a translation from the query format to the field format expected by the FilterSet; meaning change `query[first_name]` to `first_name`

Something like this might work:

```
import re

from django_filters.filterset import BaseFilterSet


class CustomParamFilterSet(BaseFilterSet):
    PARAM_REGEX = 'query\[(\w+)\]'

    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None, request=None):
        d = self.translate_data(data)
        super(CustomParamFilterSet, self).__init__(d, queryset, prefix, strict, request)

    @classmethod
    def translate_data(cls, data):
        regexp = re.compile(cls.PARAM_REGEX)
        d = dict()

        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            match = regexp.match(k)
            if match:
                new_k = match.group(1)
                d[new_k] = v
            else:
                pass  # Handle errors here

        return d
```